# danish char in latex

Tags: latex

Im running the mactex 2010 distribution with texshop. However I´m unable to get danish characters in the rendered pdf, although the text is OK within the editor (before rendering). I´ve ensured that the encoding is set to utf-8 in texshop. My preamble is

```
\documentclass[a4paper,dansk,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc,url}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[dansk]{babel}
\usepackage {graphicx}
\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{ctable} 
\usepackage{Sweave}
\usepackage[section]{placeins}
```

Any ideas what I should do?

//M

Comment: Please fix the formatting of the latex source

Answer (score 0):

Maybe:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{t1enc}
\usepackage[danish]{babel}
```

Comment: Setting `inputenc` to `latin1` is a bit counterproductive when the file is encoded with UTF-8.

Comment: the latin1 option has already been tried without any success. Even if I have the file encoded in that format. //M